# check whether the list contains item greater than a value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, contains

I need to check that a List contains or not values that are greater that a specific value. How could I doing so?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? There are several ways to do it - where are you stuck?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
bool contains = yourList.Any(z => z.YouProperty > yourValue);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any<TSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)> method. It returns `boolean`.

> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Boolean
true if the source sequence contains any elements; otherwise, false.

List.Any(a => a.Property > Value);
```